# Could this work to help prevent spambots?

Tags: spam-prevention

There's probably a ton of stuff I'm probably missing but recently I was thinking how viable it would be on forms to have users perform an action in the UI such as drag/drop a (for example) paper widget into a box widget (possibly also randomly placed on the page) to represent submission of a form.

The idea behind it being, find some action that a human would more likely be able to perform than a bot.  Would this in any way prevent spambots?

(I'm laughing as I type this btw, but I just wanted to see how crazy this idea really seemed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I don't think it would help. All that happens when a user clicks, drags and drops a component is that events (like click) get fired. You could just as easily fire those events programmatically if you were a spambot. Nice idea though.

Comment: Yeah I was also thinking about that too, I guess in the end, basically everything you do on the page can be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Like most home-made spam prevention methods, it'll work until your site is large enough that a spammer decides to pay some specific attention to your site -- at which point, it'll be broken to pieces. But there's no need to get as fancy as what you're describing. Spam-protection methods as simple as "type 'orange' into this box" or "what is one plus one" will work just as well, **as long as** your site is only being hit by automated tools.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking mainly about the automated tools, something simple enough/not too annoying for a human to do yet still prove with a high certainty that you're dealing with a human... just kind of a random idea I had.